# Algorithm for organizing emails into threads?

Tags: ruby, email, email-threading

Are there any named/famous/particularly good algorithms for organizing email messages into threads?

I'm looking to add a feature to my site similar to Google Groups (and other mailing lists) and I was just wondering if there were any published algorithms for such organizing.  I know it would probably be fairly easy to roll my own, but there can be a big difference in user experience between a passable algorithm and a good one.

Bonus points for an algorithm already implemented in ruby!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[jwz_threading](http://github.com/fdietz/jwz_threading) looks like exactly what you're asking for. I haven't used it.

Comment: Boosh!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Wish I could upvote multiple times!

Comment: We'll do the upvoting for you :)

Comment: great! is there anything like that library that works for iOS?